# What number of tracked faces does each iOS device support?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, face-detection

When checking `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.supportedNumberOfTrackedFaces` on an iPhone X running iOS 13 it returns 1. But looking at the ARKit promo page it says:

> ARKit Face Tracking tracks up to three faces at once, using the TrueDepth camera on iPhone X, iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR, and iPad Pro to power front-facing camera experiences like Memoji and Snapchat.

Is there any documentation that specifies what each device supports?

Answer (score 0):

At first I should say that only devices with TrueDepth sensor support ARFaceTracingConfiguration, so the oldest gadget in a row is iPhone X.

Secondly, to track three faces at a time you need iOS 13+, as you already said.

Thirdly, the default value is `1` face to track, thus you have to use the following instance property if you wanna simultaneously track up to three faces:

```
var maximumNumberOfTrackedFaces: Int { get set }
```

or:

```
guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported 
else {
    print("You can't track faces on this device.")
    return 
}

let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
config.maximumNumberOfTrackedFaces = 3
sceneView.session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

P.S. I haven't seen any documentation that specifies what each device supports except [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces).